# Error with Axis2 Maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, apache-axis, java2wsdl

I've been trying to create a WSDL from my Java code using the plugin supplied by Axis2, [see here](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/maven-plugins/maven-java2wsdl-plugin.html).

However when executing the goal:

```
mvn axis2-java2wsdl:java2wsdl
```

I get  the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.axis2:axis2-java2wsdl-maven-plugin:1.6.3:java2wsdl (default-cli) on project enterprise-assignment: null: MojoExecutionException: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
```

Can anyone shed any light on the problem? My project compiles, runs and installs correctly so I'm pretty sure it's not an error in my code, but perhaps something I'm missing in my pom.

Edit: My Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <groupId>org.andrewvincent</groupId>
    <artifactId>enterprise-assignment</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <app.id>enterprise-programming-1109</app.id>
        <app.version>1</app.version>
        <appengine.version>1.9.28</appengine.version>
        <gcloud.plugin.version>2.0.9.81.v20151008</gcloud.plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <cxf.version>3.1.4</cxf.version>
        <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
        <axis2.version>1.6.3</axis2.version>
    </properties>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.1.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.37</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
    <build>
        <!-- for hot reload of the web application-->
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis2-java2wsdl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${axis2.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <className>org.andrewvincent.dao.StaffDAO</className>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java2wsdl</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                            <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <webResources>
                        <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: The spaces there `org.apache.axis2:axis2-java2wsdl-maven-     plugin` are _really_ weird. Could you post your POM?

Comment: @Tunaki sorry, it was just an error in my formatting of the question. Add my pom file now.